# Upgraded to Server 4.0 and Xcode 6.1, SSH git remotes broken

Tags: xcode6, osx-server

Following my upgrade to OS X Server 4.0 and Xcode 6.1, I can no longer access my git repos as I have done previously:

```
git clone ssh://example.com/git/MyRepo.git
```

I get the error:

> fatal: '/git/MyRepo.git' does not appear to be a git
>   repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I can still log in via SSH and verify that the repos are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the symbolic link to the git repo is now incorrect. It was pointing to the old location, so I needed to point it to the new directory:

```
cd /
sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/HostedRepositories/ git
```